# C(++) short subtracting short = int?

Tags: c++, types, int, short

Have the following code:

```
short a = 5;
short b = 15;
short c = 25;

short d = std::min(a, b);
short e = std::min(a, b-c); // Error
```

The last line cannot be compiled, claiming that there's no overload of min() that matches the arguments "short, int".

What is the reason for this being the case?
I understand that the result of b-c could potentially not fit in a short anymore. However that would be the same if I were using INTs and there it doesn't automatically form a LONG or anything to enforce that it fits.

As long as I am sure that the resulting number will never exceed the range of SHORT, it is safe if I use `static_cast<short>(b-c)`, right?

Huge thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason: integer promotion. If a type is narrower than `int`, it is promoted to `int` automatically. This makes little difference for signed numbers because overflow is undefined, but for unsigned numbers for which overflow wraps, this allows the compiler to emit a lot less code for most processors.

Most of the time, this automatically casts back because assigning to a narrower variable is not an error. You happened to find a case where this really does cause an issue though.

If you're sure it fits, just cast it back.

Comment: "for most processors". That is, for most 16-bit processors. For 8 or 32 bit processors, not so much. And not even optimum for processors that emit a 32 bit result.  More a bit of history tied to early implementations.

Comment: @david: Actually that's for 32 bit processors. They would otherwise have to emit code to shear off the high bits at several places.